# How to set up a homepage at django

Tags: django

I am new to django and I want to set my homepage url

My homepage is **127.0.0.1:8000/home** but I want my homepage at **127.0.0.1:8000/** or I want my django start as **127.0.0.1:8000/home** as default. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use empty string in url path instead 'home/' for root url

For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app_name.urls'))
]
```

for urls in your app

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name="home"))
    ]
```

Comment: It's my pleasure